# perl config::scoped, can print not defined values?

Tags: perl, config

I want to use Config::scoped module in my perl code.

This is my config :

```
http_db{
          user      = 'xxx';
          pass = 'aaa';
          dbname = 'data';
          host = 'dataserver.company.cz';
}
```

When I use :

```
    my $cs          = Config::Scoped->new( file => $config);
    my $cfg_hash    = $cs->parse;
    .
    .
    .
    print $cfg_hash->{http_db}{user};  # prints xxx;
    if ( defined( $cfg_hash->{http_dp}{user} ) ) {
          print "defined"; # does not print
    else{
          print "undefined"; # prints
    }
```

I expect the if condition to be fullfilled but it is not. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your code is is exactly what you included here, it is because of a simple typo.

Your print statement uses the `http_db` key correctly, but your `if` statement uses `http_dp`.